# How to check if all textboxes in a row are filled using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 textboxes in each row. At least one of the rows should be filled completely. All the textboxes in any of the rows should not be empty. I have tried below code, it's for the first row only.

```
var filledtextboxes= $(".setup_series_form tr:first input:text").filter(function () {
  return $.trim($(this).val()) != '';
}).length;
```

We want to get the maximum number of non-empty textboxes in any row, TIA.

[image]

Comment: That's because you're only targeting `tr:first`...? Fix your selector and this will work. You may also need to loop through the rows if you want to check if the row has been filled, or if *all* rows have been filled. That part isn't clear from your description

Comment: Loop through all the rows in the table, and use `$(this).find("input:text")` to get all the textboxes in that row.

Comment: if I target all tr(which is right) how can it will work for a single variable filledtextboxes??

Comment: @Barmar, can u pl write an answer..

Comment: why downvote.. isn't it understandable..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the rows. In each row, get the number of filled boxes. If this is higher than the previous maximum, replace the maximum with this count.

```
var maxboxes = -1;
var maxrow;
$(".setup_series_form tr").each(function(i) {
    var filledtextboxes = $(this).find("input:text").filter(function () {
      return $.trim($(this).val()) != '';
    }).length;
    if (filledtextboxes > maxboxes) {
        maxboxes = filledtextboxes;
        maxrow = i;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting only first tr here  `$(".setup_series_form tr:first input:text")` so you will not get the expected output.

You have to iterate with every `row`(tr) inside `form` and then find the count of 
text field having not empty values and store in a `maxCount` variable by comparing it previous `tr` count.

**Here is a working snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {      
    var maxCountInRow =0;
    var rowNumber;
    $(".setup_series_form tr").each(function(index){                        
        var filledtextboxes= $(this).find("input:text").filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).val()) != '';
    }).length;
     if(filledtextboxes>maxCountInRow){
     maxCountInRow=filledtextboxes;
     rowNumber=index;
     }
     });  
     console.log("Row Number:"+rowNumber+" having maxCount: "+maxCountInRow);
 
});
```

```css
.registrant_table{width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: center;}
.registrant_table tr td{border: 1px solid #ccc;height: 42px;font-weight: bolder;}
.registrant_table input{border: 0px !important;width: 100%;height: 42px;text-align: center;font-weight: normal;}
label.error{color: red !important;}
.err-fields{background-color:red;color: white !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="setup_series_form">
<div>
    <table class="registrant_table">
        <tr class="title">
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Official Full Name</td>
            <td>Mobile Contact</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="in-fields">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="sas" name="firstname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="phone[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="email[]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="in-fields">
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="sas" name="firstname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="sas" name="phone[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email[]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="in-fields">
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email[]"></td>
        </tr>                   
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.